# Not able to display list on the same page received from controller through ajax call. IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to display a list on the jsp (on its loading) fetched from controller. The controller is called by ajax, and the list is also received  by ajax function as a Json response, but it gives me following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:478)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1120)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:944)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, if the list is returned empty then the success of ajax function is called, so the problem revolves around returning the arraylist as a response.

Below is my jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js>    </script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = window.location.href;
    ;
    alert(path);
    $.ajax({

        type : "GET",
        url : "displaySurvey.htm",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
            name : window.location.href
        },

        success : function(response) {
            alert("success");
            displayTheContent(response);
        },
    });
});

function displayTheContent(response) {
    alert("displayResponse");
    $("#displayDiv").empty();
    for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
        var user = response[i];
        $("#displayDiv").append(
                "<li>" + user.question + " " + user.option1 + "</li>");
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="displayDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/displaySurvey.htm")
public class DisplaySurveyController extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody  ArrayList<SurveyQuestions>  submit(@RequestParam("name") String request)
        throws AdException {
    String surveyId = request.substring(request.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);


    try {
        SurveyDAO surveyDao = new SurveyDAO();
        ArrayList<SurveyQuestions> questionList = (ArrayList<SurveyQuestions>) surveyDao.getSurveyQuestions(surveyId);
        return questionList;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new AdException("Could not list the categories", e);

    }

}
}
```

Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: is there exception on the server? please share the complete stack trace

Comment: updated with the complete stack trace.